# UITraitCollection doesn't have any information after custom segue

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, segue, uitraitcollection

When I return to my home screen after a logout, it can't return any information about its `traitCollection`. I would like to get its size class and it is not possible.

[image]

When I run the screen without any segue it has all the information:

```
print(self.view.traitCollection)

<UITraitCollection: 0x14fe47dd0; _UITraitNameUserInterfaceIdiom = Phone, _UITraitNameDisplayScale = 2.000000, _UITraitNameHorizontalSizeClass = Compact, _UITraitNameVerticalSizeClass = Regular, _UITraitNameTouchLevel = 0, _UITraitNameInteractionModel = 1, _UITraitNameForceTouchCapability = 1>
```

But when the screen runs after a custom segue, this is what it display:

```
print(self.view.traitCollection)

<UITraitCollection: 0x14fe21cc0; >
```

It doesn't have any information about the view.

The code of the custom segue is the below:

```
override func perform() {

    self.sourceViewController.presentViewController(self.destinationViewController as UIViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: where do the `prints` live? `viewDidLoad`, `viewDidAppear`,...

Comment: @RMenke sorry, I do the prints in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: How exactly do you present both instances? Please just provide more code.

Comment: @RMenke I provided more information. Let me know if you need something more

Comment: LogOut screen should not have a segue to Home. It should pop all all presented viewcontrollers until reaching the Home VC.

Comment: @RMenke the problem is that when the user is already log in, the app go directly to the tab bar controller, so the home screen is not launched. For that I need to have a segue. I forgot mention that.

Comment: You should still load Home, but present the next VC in viewDidLoad of the HomeVC. Never segue in circles.

Comment: @RMenke I can't find the way to "jump" login screen and present the next VC in viewDidLoad. Do you have any idea?